# Make div grow and shrink depending on parent size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am trying to create a widget that adapts its sizing to the size of the container. The widget can be expanded so that extra information is shown. I have three rows, and the behaviour I am looking for is:

- The first row has the size depending on the content
- The second row behaves as the first one
- The third must fill the available vertical space, making its content scrollable whenever expanded. When collpased, the widget must center itself vertically in the parent container

I apologize for the colors, but they should give a better idea. This is what I have currently:

[image: Collapsed widget]

In this case, the widget (white bg) is collapsed and centers itself in the parent container (red bg). When I click on open, the first row of content as well as the second one (containing just the button) must stay the same size and the third row must expand to fill the available space. This is what happens currently:

[image: Expanded widget]

The widget (white bg) expands correctly to fill the parent, but the expanded row (black bg) overflows. What I am instead looking for is this (The white bg should fill the parent, sorry):
[image]

This is the code (ignore the padding and colors, it was done to give a better idea, as well as the `@click` handler):

```html
<div id="searchWidget">
        <div class="row no-row-padding">
            <div class="col-12" style="background-color: blue;">
                <p style="color: white">First row of content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <hr class="solid">
            </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="row no-row-padding">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary actionButton" type="button" @click="showAdvancedOptions">Open</button>
        </div>  

        <div class="row" id="advancedOptions" style="background-color: black; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px">
            <div class="col-12" style="background-color: purple">
                <div class="collapse" ref="advancedOptionsCollapse" style="background-color: yellow">
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                        
    </div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```css
#searchWidget {
    padding: 16px;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}
```

I tried all possible combinations using flex but I am struggling to find one that works. I have tried setting all the possible `flex` combinations but I cannot find one that will expand AND contract the third row.

I am using Bootstrap 4.0.0 and the [collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/) component, as well as Vue.js if that helps.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have been able to figure it out, using flex:

```css
#searchWidget {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

#advancedOptions {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex-basis: auto;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

This way the container shrinks when collapsed, and takes up the available space making the third row scrollable when expanded

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you put `overflow:hidden` on the parent (searchWidget), and `overflow:auto` on the 3rd row..

https://www.codeply.com/p/qyAqKJlMTz

```
  <div id="searchWidget" class="vh-100 d-flex flex-column overflow-hidden justify-content-center">
        <div class="row no-row-padding">
            <div class="col-12" style="background-color: blue;">
                <p style="color: white">First row of content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <hr class="solid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-row-padding">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary actionButton" type="button" @click="showAdvancedOptions()">Open</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row overflow-auto" id="advancedOptions" style="background-color: black; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px">
            <div class="col-12" style="background-color: purple">
                <div :class="collapseClasses" ref="advancedOptionsCollapse" style="background-color: yellow">
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This method does work, but it does not shrink the searchWidget when it is compressed. Check my answer for how I solved it